# Restart angular app after its html has been replaced

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angular

So I'm working on and application that is a terrible mix of MVC and Angular2.

On my Index page we have a partialview loading the angular app. The index page also has all other javascripts links that are needed to get the angular app working.

This all works fine on the first load, but there's an asynchronous call that calls this grid partial view again and replaces the Angular application with `<my-app>Loading...</my-app>`.

**Question**

Is there a way in javascript to reload/restart the angular application after this asynchronous call has been made and the html has been replaced?

**Index** (main view)

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("Grid")
</div>
```

**Grid** (partial view)

```
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

---

Let me know if I need to do a more in depth explanation.

**EDIT**

My limited knowledge of Angular suggest that there should be a way to re-run the javascripts that are run on the first load. Isn't it that simple? Just run the boot.js again or something similar? I mean the `<my-app>` tag is already there.

Answer (score 2):

This was already answered in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7009) a while back but I don't think it is valid on angular 4 anymore

---

Honestly, This is kind tricky but my idea (I didn't try this) is to do the same on the module bootstrapping level 
in the `main.ts`

```
export var applicationRef;
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then((_appRef) => {applicationRef= _appRef}

);
```

then you can call `destroy()` on `applicationRef` and then you bootstrap the app again to reload it.

Comment: Hm, how would I get hold of the `applicationRef` variable in my module? I tried making it a global variable and as a shared service but neither exposed the variable globally.

Comment: did you add the `export` keyword in front of the variable?

Comment: It said exports wasn't defined. But I'll leave this for now, it doesn't seem to be a simple solution to this. Thank you for your help though!